# Phonegap adding 20px margin on top, but then cutting off bottom content?

Tags: css, cordova, ios7

For phonegap on iOS 7, I added this trick to offset the content for the new status bar:

`document.body.style.marginTop = "20px";`

This works like a charm, but then cuts off the bottom content by 20px.  Is there any way I can add the offset but not have the bottom cut off?

Comment: I think you need not to add margintop to body for iOS7. I did the same in my latest project. When I downloaded the app from appstore, Status bar is shown by default and extra 20 px was added as margin. Thats 20 px margin for staus and body. Do some research before you submit the app.

Comment: On the contrary, I do need to add the margin, else my entire content will be moved up.

Comment: Without margin, statusbar is inside the content. Right? But I think apple will do this for us and when u download app from store, statusbar will be as usual as in versions <= 6.1. Please let me know after publishing your app.

Comment: Nope, not right.  It's fine for iOS 6, but moves content up for 7.

Comment: I m talking about iOS 7. Without margin, statusbar is inside the content in iOS7. But I think we need not add margin top, apple will do this for us when uploaded to store. App downloaded from store has status bar outside the content in iOS7 as normal. I m saying this from my experience, though only with a single app. Please do some research before you submit the app.

Comment: Trust me, my research is my own app.  With Cordova 3.1, the app is moved up 20px and overlapped by navigation bar.